# Reorder rows callback with Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I'm using Bootstrap Table with Reorder Rows extension. I've followed the [documentation guide](https://bootstrap-table.com/versions/1.15.5/docs/extensions/reorder-rows/) but I don't get a callback function when I reorder a row in my table. This is the event:

> **onReorderRow(reorder-row.bs.table)** Fired when the row was dropped, receives two parameters:
>
> The new table data The dropped row The row of the old position

And I'm using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Initialise the table
  $("#table").tableDnD();
});

$(document).change(function() {
  $("#table").tableDnD();
});

$(function () {
    $('#table').on('reorder-row.bs.table', function (e, data){
        alert('close')
    });
});

</script>
```

Well, for now it would be fine if I could get the alert() (later I'm going to call another function when the row is dropped. But I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add this option on your table :
**data-use-row-attr-func="true"**

```
<table id="bootstrap-table"
  data-use-row-attr-func="true"
  data-reorderable-rows="true"
  data-on-drag-class="bs-dragged-row">
  [...]
</table>
```